# Move Google Calendar Gmail gadget to top right

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

Is there any way to move the Google Calendar Gadget to the top right in Gmail?

I have tried enabling the following labs:

- Google Calendar gadget
- Navbar drag and drop
- Right-side chat

... but couldn't get it to work. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using [stylist](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd) for chrome (should also work in the firefox version).

i added this script for domain 'mail.google.com':

```
div.nH.T4.pp + div.pp + div.nH.pp.ps.TZ { 
 position:absolute !important; 
 right:0px; 
 top:430px; 
 width:172px; 
}
```

Should work for you, adjust the top value as you wish, this works well for my resolution.

Comment: I tried using this, but it doesn't look right. Could you explain which settings you are using? Is the chat panel displayed? It the lab which places in on the right enabled? Did you drag the Google Calendar widget up or down in the list of panels on the left?

Comment: i am still not able to make any edits. I have tried this even with the help of stylist... but with no success